# map(NaN) which returns NaN but I cannot debug for NaN

Tags: java, processing

I have included a snippet that demonstrates my problem.
Basically processing gives me this error:

`map(NaN, -3, 3, -125, 125) called, which returns NaN (not a number)`

The way I understand this message is that the map function returns NaN and since it returns a float I should be able to check with Float.NaN. As demonstrated though I do not get a single hit when creating an if statement that checks it. I have tried to put the if statement before the map function with the according variables but no hits. I was wondering if someone could explain this phenomenon to me and help me with debugging the code. It is probably some small thing I am overseeing but it drives me nuts. Thanks in advance

Snippet:

```
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
}

class Complex {
  private float re, im, r, p;

  Complex(float real, float imag) {
    re = real;
    im = imag;
    r = sqrt(sq(re)+sq(im)); //radius 
    p = atan2(im, re);       //phase
  }

  Complex Div(Complex b) {
    Complex a = this;
    float real = (a.re*b.re+a.im*b.im)/(sq(b.re)+sq(b.im));
    float imag = (a.im*b.re-a.re*b.im)/(sq(b.re)+sq(b.im));
    return new Complex(real, imag);
  }

  Complex Ln() {
    float real = log(r);
    float imag = p;
    return new Complex(real, imag);
  }

  Complex LogBase(Complex b) {
    Complex a = this;
    return a.Ln().Div(b.Ln());
  }

  Complex Scale(float scale, int dim) {
    float real = map(re, -scale, scale, -dim, dim);
    float imag = map(im, -scale, scale, -dim, dim);
    if (real == Float.NaN || imag == Float.NaN) {
      print("\nHit!");
    }
    return new Complex(real, imag);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  float d = width/4;
  for (float z = -d; z<d; z++) {
    for (float x = -d; x<d; x++) {
      Complex c = new Complex(1, 5);
      c = c.LogBase(new Complex(x, z));
      c.Scale(3.0, int(d));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the misunderstanding is around comparisons to NaN.  Any equivalence comparison (==) with NaN will return false.  This is the case even when comparing with itself.  To check for a NaN value you can use the Float.isNaN method.

So for example

```
    System.out.println("(Float.NaN == Float.NaN) -> " + (Float.NaN == Float.NaN));
    System.out.println("(Float.isNaN(Float.NaN)) -> " + (Float.isNaN(Float.NaN)));
```

produces:

```
(Float.NaN == Float.NaN) -> false
(Float.isNaN(Float.NaN)) -> true
```

Comment: Thank you that actually makes a lot of sense!